# Populating ListView from a SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

```
public class ConnectDatabase extends Activity {
    private SimpleDBAdapter mDbHelper;
    private ListView list;
    private String[] values;
    private String[] list1;
    private int i=0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        list=(ListView )findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);

        mDbHelper = new SimpleDBAdapter(ConnectDatabase.this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        mDbHelper.open();
        values = mDbHelper.getEditTextValue();
        mDbHelper.close();

        for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
            String tempvalue;
            tempvalue=values[i];
            list1[i]=tempvalue;
            Log.v("log_tag"," tempvalue   "+tempvalue);
            Log.v("log_tag", "list1 is"+list1[i]);

            //Log.v("log_tag"," list1"+list1[i]); 
        }

        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values));

        //list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        //list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
                    String templist=values[i];
                    list1[i]=templist;

                }*/

                String fname=values[position];
                Log.v("log_tag", "The fname is"+ fname);
                Intent intent=new Intent(ConnectDatabase.this, Userinfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("FirstName",fname );
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    // to remove the last comma

    }
}
```

Here I am doing `ListView` from SQLite database and want to display in `ListView` with only the first 10 ListView rows at the time but I get the error at the line `list1[i]=tempvalue;` so I can't copy array here anyone can help me to do copy the array name values where I get all the Column index values from my SQLite database.

Hope anyone have an idea to do this.

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting (especially of the code) and a little bit the text of the message, but it's still almost incomprehensible. If you want somebody to help you first make your message understandable and report the errors you're getting.

Comment: Fixed up your code formatting but the actual question is not understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post is quite hard to read, but I think the issue is that `list1` has not been initialised.

You need to add a line like this:

```
list1 = new String[10];
```

before you attempt to set a value within the array.

ps - I picked a value of `10` as your `for` loop has `i<10`.

Comment: i add the list1 = new String[values.length];  instead of list1 = new String[10]; because i want the list from values the variable values is get from my DBAdapter it should be dynamic